# Python function to return concatenated string from a list, where the length of the string is more than 2 characters

Tags: python, list, iteration, string-concatenation

Newbie learning Python here, be nice!!

I have an assignment as part of my course to write simple programs, but there is one I am struggling with. For all elements in a list that have more than 2 characters, should be concatenated. The code itself is working, but it's returning the first string in the list as well as the other strings which are more than 2 characters. It's because of the way I have written the code I know, but I can't figure out a way to exclude the first string. Iteration should be utilised.

My code:

```
def concatenate(strings):
    start = strings[0]
    for string in strings:
        if len(string) > 2:
            start += string
    return start

print(concatenate(["a", "de", "fg", "hijk", "abc"]))
```

It's correctly concatenating hijkabc, but it's also including the "a" at the beginning, so the result I'm actually getting is ahijkabc.

What do I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the desired output for this example list of yours `["a", "de", "fg", "hijk", "abc"]`? Better yet, what should the output be for `["a", "de", "fg", "c", "abc"]`?

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized start with strings[0]
Just initialize start ="" as an empty string.

```
def concatenate(strings):
start = ""
for string in strings:
    if len(string) > 2:
        start += string
return start
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel really silly now, it was such an easy fix!

Comment: Its alright things like these happen when you are starting out. The real deal is not to get demotivated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, here is a way to do it:

```
from itertools import groupby

res = [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: len(x)>1)]
```

---

So for `lst = ["a", "de", "fg", "hijk", "abc"]` (your example) you get:

```
['a', 'defghijkabc']
```

and for `lst = ["a", "de", "fg", "b", "abc"]` you get:

```
['a', 'defg', 'b', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that you're looking for

```
def concatenate(strings):
    return ''.join(filter(lambda x: len(x) >2, strings))
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Thanks - I just needed an empty string to begin with, so

```
start = ''
```

Rather than

```
start = strings[0]
```

It was as easy as that, and now I feel silly! But, it's all a learning curve.
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score -1):

Initialize the `start` variable with empty string.

```
def concatenate(strings):
    start = ''
    for string in strings:
        if len(string) > 2:
            start += string
    return start
```

Comment: what is your question actually?